# Python - Divide a string

Tags: python, string, split

Hi I would like to know how I can split a string when a [ ] occur and turn the string into a list like the following :

`str = "I wish to have a[dancing marshmellow]cat,[becase I am the]best loki joki ipock`
into :

`str = ["I wish to have a","[dancing marshmellow]","cat,","[becase I am the]","best loki joki ipock"]`

I tried using
`str.split("[")`
But it didnt divide it correctly since i need the text in between both [ and [ to be included in the output str[]

Comment: Welcome here, what is the exact output you expect? What code have you already tried?

Comment: Why does the string get split at `a[ dancing` but not `cat, [because`?

Comment: Because the string is divided into parts of before [ ] and after so

Comment: I wish to have a 1 part then there is a [ dancing marshmallows] so its another part  then there is the cat and then again the [ because iom the is splitting our string]

Comment: i expect an output like the 2nd str that is a list ,

Comment: if you divide in parts before and after `[` and `]` then it should be `, 'cat, ', `, also which parts do you want to be strings? the expected output is invalid because it has no strings or anything, just a lot of undefined names

Comment: Sorry I'll fix the output  I didnt write it properly :)

Comment: Fixed it, now it should be more clear of what output I am looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex pattern to find all the matching groups and then use a list comprehension and `join` method to create a list that will be in your expected form:

```py
import re

string = "I wish to have a[dancing marshmellow]cat,[becase I am the]best loki joki ipock"
pattern = re.compile(r'(\[.*?\])|((?<=\]).*?(?=\[|$))|(^.*?(?=\[|$))')
lst = [''.join(s) for s in pattern.findall(string)]
print(lst)
# output
# ['I wish to have a', '[dancing marshmellow]', 'cat,', '[becase I am the]', 'best loki joki ipock']
```

Useful:

- [`re` library docs (built-in)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
s="I wish to have a[dancing marshmellow]cat,[becase I am the]best loki joki ipock"
res = []
slowRunner = 0
for index in range(len(s)):
    if(s[index] == "["  and slowRunner != index-1):
        res.append(s[slowRunner:index])
        slowRunner = index
    elif(s[index] == "]" and s[index+1] != " "):
        res.append("["+s[slowRunner+1:index]+"]")
        slowRunner = index+1
    elif s[index] == "[":
        print(index)
        res.append(s[slowRunner:index])
        slowRunner = index
        
# Remaining string
if(slowRunner < len(s)-1):
    res.append(s[slowRunner:len(s)])
print(res)
```

Output

```
['I wish to have a', '[dancing marshmellow]', 'cat,', '[becase I am the]', 'best loki joki ipock']
```

**NOTE**:

**If this is not what you're expecting, you may use strip() and replace() methods to achieve the desired output.**

Do let me know if this works. Thanks

Comment: Oh I get it, that [] should a string. Let me just fix that

Comment: Exactly the [] is a part of the string :) not a new list

Comment: I made the necessary changes. Please check now

Comment: Thanks haha but Mattis solution was better for me I guess :)